# SQL - How to avoid inserting duplicate rows from another table while matching multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using Microsoft SSMS.

There are two tables

**Table1**

```
ID | SessionId | Handle  | StartDate          |
---------------------------------
1  | abcd      | handle1 | 2020-08-01 00:00:00|
2  | abcd      | handle2 | 2020-08-01 00:00:00|
```

**TempTable**

```
SessionId | Handle  | StartDate          |
---------------------------------
 abcd     | handle1 | 2020-08-01 00:00:00|
 abcd     | handle2 | 2020-08-01 00:00:00|
 abcd     | handle3 | 2020-08-01 00:00:00|  --only this record has to be inserted to Table1
```

I want to insert only the last row in `TempTable` to `Table1`, because the other 2 records are present already.

A row is a duplicate only when all the column values in `TempTable` match with a record on `Table1`.

I'm not sure how to use `NOT IN` or `INTERSECT` or any other alternate, as there are multiple column values to be matched.

**UPDATE:**

Following @llyes suggestion, helped me resolve this.

```
INSERT INTO table1 (SessionId, Handle, StartDate)
SELECT SessionId, Handle, StartDate
FROM TempTable t2
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM Table1 t1
    WHERE t1.SessionId= t2.SessionId
    AND t1.Handle = t2.Handle   
    AND t1.StartDate = t2.StartDate 
);
```

Comment: Might be easier to write as `INSERT INTO...SELECT...WHERE NOT EXISTS (...)` and subquery the target table.

Comment: That would be easy using `EXCEPT`

Comment: @ATOMP What will be the subquery like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `EXCEPT` as the following

```
SELECT SessionId, Handle, StartDate
FROM
(
  VALUES
  ('abcd', 'handle1', '2020-08-01 00:00:00'),
  ('abcd', 'handle2', '2020-08-01 00:00:00'),
  ('abcd', 'handle3', '2020-08-01 00:00:00')
) TempTable(SessionId, Handle, StartDate)
EXCEPT
SELECT SessionId, Handle, StartDate
FROM
(
  VALUES
  (1, 'abcd', 'handle1', '2020-08-01 00:00:00'),
  (2, 'abcd', 'handle2', '2020-08-01 00:00:00')
) YourTable(ID, SessionId, Handle, StartDate);
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3d14bf1cc389a9b50cafe82ad0fe84d3)

You could also use `NOT EXISTS()` as

```
SELECT *
FROM TempTable TT
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
                  SELECT 1
                  FROM YourTable YT
                  WHERE YT.SessionId = TT.SessionId
                        AND YT.Handle = TT.Handle 
                        AND YT.StartDate = TT.StartDate
                );
```

Comment: @llyes Do we need to manually specify the values. There will be many number of rows.

Comment: @Qwerty No, just write `FROM TempTable / FROM Table1` directly